# Regex to accept alphanumberic, whitespace and - in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the Regex to accept **alphanumeric, whitespace and -** in Javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: Do you want **only** those?

Answer (score 3):

```
"HI THERE 0-9 are valid characters".match(/[a-z0-9\s-]+/i)
```

- `a-z` will match your favourite alphabet (the roman one!)
- `0-9` will match your favourite numerals (the arabic ones!)
- `\s` will (probably) match your favourite whitespace characters (\f, \n, \r, \t, \v, \u00A0, \u2028, and \u2029)
- `-`, since it's at the end of the set, will match a literal `-`.
- The `i` modifier at the end of the regex makes it case-insensitive, so `a-z` will also match `A-Z`.

Comment: Probably the OP wants only those characters, so `/^[\w\s-]*$]/` may suit better, and is less to type. Oh, and "whitespace" matched by \s may be slightly different in different browsers and many not match everything that is recognised as white space. :-)

Comment: An explanation would be nice. Otherwise, he won't learn.

Comment: @RobG `\w` includes `_`. String anchors are a good idea, though

Comment: @JanDvorak you're right - this was a cop-out answer. I'll add some more detail.

Comment: Ah, forgot that pesky underscore. >:(

Comment: do you mind if I add some formatting to the explanation?

Comment: Done. I don't like walls of text :-)

Comment: also, there probably _should_ be string anchors (`^...$`) so that the full string must be matched

Comment: There probably should be... There's a lot of assumption required to answer this question in any meaningful fashion anyway, so I'm not opposed to adding those in.

Comment: @deoxxa copout is a word. You don't need to hyphenate it.